# How do I rename the columns while using concat and create a pipe delimited file while writing query in Hue - Impala?

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I am writing :

```
select concat(col1 , '|', col2 , '|', col3 , '|', col4 ,'|', col5)
```

I tried using AS to get the column names but get an error.

```
concat(col1 as parent, '|', col2 as child, '|', .....)
```

Output should have the individual col names as well. I need the header - which should be the column names:

```
parent|child|date|year|month
```

Comment: I formatted the question, though I find it not clear

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select str
from (select 'parent, child, . . . ' as str, 1 as ordering
      union all
      select concat(col1, '|', col2, '|', col3, '|', col4, ' |', col5) as str
      from t
     ) t
order by ordering;
```

Comment: So I am joining two tables and selecting columns from both. This doesn't seem to work. I just want to rename the columns so that they appear as Header.

Comment: @Mrinal . . . That is what this does.  It adds an *additional* row with the heading.

Comment: I am not able to define 't' as I am joining two tables.

Comment: @Mrinal . . . That is whatever your query is.

Comment: So, I have :    from DB.tableA mt inner join DB1.tableB ch on D=E where q='ch'..........How shall I define t here